# What is that suburban commercial area off the highway called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is that suburban commercial un-walkable McDonald’s-stuffed area that you would find off the side of a highway called?

Here’s the best image I could find:

[image: Image of a highway]

I pass by them and go through them all the time on road trips.

I’ve considered “sprawl” but it doesn’t really fit.

Comment: It doesn't have a name.

Comment: Can you give a clearer description. What does it include? How does it differ from other areas? Maybe aerial photos, maps, Google Maps links. Your pic just looks like a fast food restaurant but I guess you're not wanting us to identify a Burger King.

Answer (score 3):

That is a **strip,** defined [by MW as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strip)

> a commercially developed area especially along a highway

[Or by Cambridge as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/strip)

> a row of stores and small businesses built together along the side of a main road

Depending on its size, it might also be called a **strip mall.**

[MW defines this as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strip%20mall)

> a long usually one-story building or group of buildings housing several adjacent retail stores or service establishments

[Cambridge gives a somewhat more specific definition:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/strip-mall)

> a shopping area consisting of a row of stores, restaurants, other businesses and a place for cars to park, especially along a busy road

A larger stretch of this may be called a **stroad,** a neologism [defined by Wikipedia thus:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroad#:%7E:text=A%20stroad%20is%20a%20type,structures%20in%20the%20United%20States.)

> According to Marohn, a stroad is a bad combination of two types of vehicular pathways: it is part *street*—which he describes as a "complex environment where life in the city happens", with pedestrians, cars, buildings close to the sidewalk for easy accessibility, with many (property) entrances / exits to and from the street, and with spaces for temporary parking and delivery vehicles—and part *road,* which he describes as a "high-speed connection between two places" with wide lanes and limited entrances and exits, and which are generally straight or have gentle curves.

Comment: A strip mall normally has connected buildings, dedicated parking in front of the stores, and is not bisected by cross streets, as the stores in the photo are.

Comment: **Strip** is closer but it refers to a section of road with retail location after retail location. You can drive a vehicle down the strip. "Kids were driving up and down the strip in candy-colored Fords and Chevys..."  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Center_Line/ZMDYBQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=driving+down+the+strip&pg=PT132&printsec=frontcover

Comment: A convincing and well referenced answer that applies well to America. I don’t think we use “strip” in Britain but I cannot think of an alternative. It looks a dump but that word is too general and insulting to qualify.

Comment: The Cambridge lexicographers have not got it right. Close, but no cigar. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22driving%20down%20the%20strip%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1985,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en

Answer (score -3):

I think it is called “[rest area](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rest_area)”:

> A rest area is a public facility located next to a large thoroughfare such as a motorway, expressway, or highway, at which drivers and passengers can rest, eat, or refuel without exiting onto secondary roads.
>
> Other names include motorway service area, services (UK), ***travel plaza, rest stop, oasis (US).***

(Wikipedia)

Comment: What's pictured isn't a rest area, it's a commercial strip that also serves the local community. A highway rest area exclusively serves travelers, there being no local access to it.